# ReactJS redux saga fetch api

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I have following code in my ReactJS app that is not working on IE11 browser. The problem is with `fetch` call on IE11 browser. Application is not making the API call to server.

It works great on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge. Could anyone please suggest what steps do I need to perform to support IE11 also? Thanks.

```
function toQueryString(obj) {
    var parts = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            parts.push(encodeURIComponent(i) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[i]));
        }
    }
    return parts.join("&");
}
var options = new Object;
options.searchoptions = JSON.stringify(searchoptions);
options.limit = limit;
options.offset = offset;
var optionstr = toQueryString(options);

return fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/api/resource/?${optionstr}`, {
  method: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
  }
}).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(response => {
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  return data;
}).then(json => {
  return json;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fetch is not supported in IE 11.
but you can use a polyfill https://github.com/github/fetch

You might also need a promise polyfill like babel-polyfill. 
https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Notice: It includes more than just promise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I really appreciate your help. I have one question. Will I be required to change my existing code? Is it just installing and adding import statement or anything more is required?

Comment: Just need to install and import the polyfill. No need to change your code. Cause their implementation is following the native fetch.